# How to reference current search results in a subquery

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to find sentences with two words adjecent to each other, using Postgres directly, not some command language extension. My tables are:

```
TABLE word (
    spelling text,
    wordid serial
)
TABLE sentence (
    sentenceid serial
)
TABLE item (
    sentenceid integer, 
    position smallint, 
    wordid integer
)
```

I have a simple query to find sentences with a single word:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sentence.sentenceid 
FROM item, word, sentence 
WHERE 
    word.spelling = 'word1' AND 
    item.wordid = word.wordid AND 
    sentence.sentenceid = item.sentenceid
```

and what I want is to filter that in turn by some word whose corresponding item has a item.sentenceid = the current query result's item (or sentence).sentenceid and
item.position = the current query result's item.position + 1

I don't see that ALIAS's work, and I don't know how to reference current state of the query in a subquery.

Comment: Could you add some sample data and the expected output? I for one have a hard time understanding what exactly you mean with "current query result's position" and "current query result's position + 1". It *sounds* as if you are looking for the `lead()` or `lag()` function

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct sentenceid
from
    item i
    inner join
    item i2 using (sentenceid)
    inner join
    word w on w.wordid = i.wordid
    inner join
    word w2 on w2.wordid = i2.wordid
where
    w.spelling = 'word1' and
    w2.spelling = 'word2' and
    i.position = i2.position - 1
```